# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I know, this topic have but I have similar problem.
My localhost have some datas.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Where is my mistake? Please help me. :(

app.js

```
'use strict';
(function () {
let myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    myApp.controller('userController', ['$http', function ($http) {
        let vm = this;
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Market/users").then(function (response) {
            vm.usersForm = response.data;
        })
    }]);

    myApp.config('$stateProvider', [ function($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: "http://localhost:63342/demo2/app/",
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: "userController"
        })
    }]);

}());
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController as vm">

    <label>{{vm.usersForm.firstName}}</label>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debug my index.html, console screen:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.32/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1511:11)
    at assertArgFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1521:3)
    at annotate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3291:5)
    at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3945:21)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3886:37
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3873:5)
    at createInjector (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3813:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1446:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.32/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'fn'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.32%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A78%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArg%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A1511%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArgFn%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A1521%3A3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20annotate%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3291%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3945%3A21)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3886%3A37%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A325%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3873%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3813%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A1446%3A20)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1511:11)
    at assertArgFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1521:3)
    at annotate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3291:5)
    at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3945:21)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3886:37
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3873:5)
    at createInjector (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3813:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1446:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.32/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'fn'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.32%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A78%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArg%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A1511%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArgFn%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A1521%3A3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20annotate%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3291%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3945%3A21)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3886%3A37%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A325%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3873%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A3813%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.32%2Fangular.js%3A1446%3A20)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:78:12
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3907:15
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3873:5)
    at createInjector (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:3813:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1446:20)
    at bootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1461:12)
    at angularInit (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:1370:5)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:22192:5
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js:2575:7)
```

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Replace `myApp.config('$stateProvider', [ function($stateProvider) {` with `myApp.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {`. The opening square bracket `[` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Comment: I edited like this  apps.config('provider', ['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {  
    and repeating Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I added this library:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

app.js is updated

```
'use strict';
(function () {
let myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

    myApp.controller('userController', ['$http', function ($http) {
        let vm = this;
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Market/users").then(function (response) {
            vm.usersForm = response.data;
        })
    }]);

    myApp.config('$stateProvider', [ function($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: "http://localhost:63342/demo2/app/",
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: "userController"
        })
    }]);

}());
```

index.html is updated

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController as vm">

    <label>{{vm.usersForm.firstName}}</label>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```